# Tcp Listener socket only used for establishing connections or to handle all incomming data?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

Will a listening Tcp Socket create a new socket for each established connection to handle incomming data from a specific client? This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26374740/5342935 suggest the following:

> the server's original socket is never used for actually communicating over a connection. It's simply the socket that's used to create connections.

However: I built a basic Tcp/Ip application and looked at the packets via wireshark, and found out that the data that is sent from the client to the server is sent to the same ip:port (= same socket, according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/152863/5342935 (suggests that a Socket is just one endpoint of a connection.)) as the connection request. Due to the upvotes to the first answer link above, I first thought it may be simply wrong, however multiple people confirmed it being right, which confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct but conclusion is wrong :-)

The listening socket is really used to just establish the connection. The data transfer connection then uses the same pair of client and server port but operating system distributes the data to different socket channels specific to client it belongs to.

Comment: I think I understand it now, thanks. But doesn't that mean that you can kind of have multiple Sockets / socket-channels, awaiting data on the same ip:port? I was told there can only be one socket listening to one ip:port pair (or maybe i was interpreting something wrong?)

Comment: There is one socket listening for new connection but once the new connection is accepted it's open until closed by either side. There can be many of them waiting for and sending data. Just a bote - it's possible to specify REUSE_PORT and then there can be several listeners on the same port.

Comment: @WhosDatDev, IP has its own addresses, not ports. Ports are transport-layer addresses. Each transport-layer protocol has its own address scheme. TCP and UDP call their addresses, "ports," and each has its own set of ports. You could use the same port number on both TCP and UDP at the same time for different things.